# Getting my External Hard drive to work on my MacBook Air 2012

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, macbook-air

I'm very much not tech savvy and never had to use an external hard drive but my computer is running out of space and I can't get my external hard drive to work properly. Is it supposed to automatically add on to my drive or am I supposed to use it like a flash drive? My computer keeps telling me I'm running out of space and I've searched everywhere! No Apple Store near me either so I don't know what to do!

I am in college and use my computer nearly 24/7 so please help! If I have to get an internal hard drive to work I can but I don't want to since this was $80.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't "automatically add on to your drive". 
If you know how to use a flash drive,
that should be good enough to get you started.